# I still wasn't able to get help for this Jquery event below

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, javascript-framework, jquery-events

In the ESNList text field , multiple values need to be entered separated with a comma , yet they have to be in the same range .. For example , in the condition below in the loop , if you input a number in ESNList between 986329 and 999999 , the second input in the ESNList field after the comma should be in the same range as the first input and so on otherwise I throw an alert saying that Both ESNs should be in the same range .. I did a loop to perform the check but it's not working .. Can someone demonstrate to me where the error is .. a fiddle would help tons ,

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {


    $(":text").css("border", "2px solid red");
      $(":text").keyup(function(){
        var enteredData = $(this).val()
        console.log(enteredData);
        if (enteredData == "") {
          $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
        } else {
          $(this).css("border", "inherit");
        }
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNList"){
       esnList = enteredData.split(',');
           }

           for(var i = 0; i < esnList.length; i++) {
            if  ( parseInt(esnList[i]) >= 986329 && parseInt(esnList[i]) <= 999999) {
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("stx2");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                }
            else if ( parseInt(esnList[i]) >= 660000 && parseInt(esnList[i]) <= 699999) {
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("mmt");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                 }
            else if ( parseInt(esnList[i]) >= 200000 && parseInt(esnList[i]) <= 299999) {
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("stmcomtech");
                 }
            else if ( parseInt(esnList[i]) >= 1202114 && parseInt(esnList[i]) <= 1299999) {
                $("#ddl_StxName").val("smartone");
                $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
          }

          else { alert("ESNs should be within the same range"); }

        }


      });
      });
    </script> </head>
    <body>
    <form id="provision">
        ESNList:    <input  type="text" id="ESNList" name="ESNList" size="30" /> <br />
        ESN Start:<input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
        ESN End: <input type="text" id="ESNStart" name="ESNStart" size="10" /> <br />
        UnitName:<input type="text" id="STxName" name="STxName" size="30"  />  <br />  
         Unit Model:   <select name="STxName" id="ddl_StxName">
        <option value="stx2">STX2</option>
        <option value="stm3" selected>STM3</option>
        <option value="acutec">Acutec</option>
         <option value="trackpack">Trackpack</option>
        <option value="mmt">MMT</option>
        <option value="smartone">Smartone</option>
        <option value="smartoneb" >SmartOneB</option>
        </select> <br />
        RTU Model Type:
         <select name="rtumodel" id ="ddl_rtumodel">
        <option value="globalstar">GlobalStar</option>
        <option value="both">Both</option>
        <option value="comtech">Comtech</option>
        <option value="stmcomtech">STMComtech</option>
        </select> <br />
        <input type="submit" value ="submit"  />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "a fiddle would help tons" – yes indeed.

Comment: Just as a matter of ettiquette, you should consider creating a fiddle with your code, rather than expecting others to create one for you. We're doing you the courtesy of trying to help you learn... and obviously, you know about jsFiddle, so expecting someone else to do that setup might be construed as expecting other volunteers to use time you won't invest, yourself. In my case, I have some time on my hands, today, thus my answer below, but that's not going to happen often. OTOH,  you gave us code to look at, which a lot of noobs never bother with, so kudos, there! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my, where to start?

For one thing, keyup is going to be triggered after each successive keyup event, which means you're going to do a lot of comparisons over and over again, and get a lot of "negatives" before the user has even finished putting in the first value.

To save some pain, I started with your code, in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/68s68/

(Notice that I placed a textarea at the bottom to serve as an output, so you can see exactly how the range-checks are occurring. I also commented out the alert, as that, in combination with keyup, was creating a pretty nasty loop.)

The problem is that each comparison only exists within the context of the current value... it can't tell what the "start range" should be because you're not storing any such thing to compare against, so, when it comes to the next value in the loop, it's only testing to see if the item it currently is looking at is within the specified ranges, NOT that it falls into the same range as the last looked-up item.

You might do that by storing the first comparison in an outside variable, and then comparing every value after the first against the range that is saved in that outside variable. See the code below for an example to get you started. Also, see it in context, here:
http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/68s68/2/

```
$(function () {
    var out = $("#output");
    var debug = function(txtIn){
        out.val(out.val() + "\n" + txtIn);
    };
    // store your ranges here, in an array
    var ranges = [
        [986329,999999],
        [660000,699999],
        [200000,299999],
        [1202114,1299999]
    ];

    // store the activeRange that is set by the first item in the comparison loop
    var activeRange = -1;

    // use this to test the a value against a given range array
    var withinRange = function(comparitor, range) {
        return (comparitor >= range[0] && comparitor <= range[1]);
    };

    $(":text").css("border", "2px solid red");
    // start the test onBlur, rather than on keyup
    $(":text").blur(function () {
        var enteredData = $(this).val()
        console.log(enteredData);
        if (enteredData == "") {
            $(this).css("border", "2px solid red");
        } else {
            $(this).css("border", "inherit");
        }
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "ESNList") {
            esnList = enteredData.split(',');
        }

        // loop through your values...
        for (var i = 0; i < esnList.length; i++) {
            // store the current value, rather than re-parseInt'ing it for every comparison
            var intVal = parseInt(esnList[i]);

            debug("intVal = " + intVal);

            // now, find out if an activeRange has been set
            if(activeRange == -1) {
                // if not, we need to find out what the activeRange is
                if (withinRange(intVal, ranges[0])) {
                    activeRange = ranges[0];
                } else if (withinRange(intVal, ranges[1])) {
                    activeRange = ranges[1];
                } else if (withinRange(intVal,ranges[2])) {
                    activeRange = ranges[2];
                } else if (withinRange(intVal,ranges[3])) {
                    activeRange = ranges[3];
                }
            } else {
                // if an activeRange has been set already, 
                // we need to find out if the current item is outside the activeRange
                if (!withinRange(intVal, activeRange)) {
                    debug("Value out of active range.");
                }
            }

            // Now that you know what your activeRange should be, you can
            // decide what to set your drop down lists to reflect
            switch (activeRange) {
                case ranges[0]:
                    $("#ddl_StxName").val("stx2");
                    $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                    break;
                case ranges[1]:
                    $("#ddl_StxName").val("mmt");
                    $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                    break;
                case ranges[2]:
                    $("#ddl_StxName").val("stm3");
                    $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("stmcomtech");                        
                    break;
                case ranges[3]:
                    $("#ddl_StxName").val("smartone");
                    $("#ddl_rtumodel").val("globalstar");
                    break;
                default:
                    debug("Value out of range.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```